# Express: How to properly use route paramters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm setting up routes for in my express server. As I tried to use it with a route paramter, I stumbled upon a problem:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(rootPublic + '/pages/recipes/edit.html')
})
```

Is it possible to somehow send the data of the object I want to edit with the response? Or is it only possible to use the id as a query parameter and read the data on document load?

Comment: Please, be more clear. Which object you want to edit?

Comment: It depends a bit on what the data is?  One would typically use a template engine and combine the data with an HTML template and the rendered template has the data inserted into the HTML page and that is what is sent to the user so they get the HTML document with the data already in it.  It's also possible to rely on Javascript in the page and use an Ajax call to request the additional resource after the page loads and then use the Javascript to insert it into the page.  This is generally slower and opens up an API to request resources.

Comment: When I go to /edit/:id I want to get the information of something from my DB. That information should be displayed in a form. The data is therefore a simple JSON Object

Comment: So if I understand right, its not possible to do so without a view engine?